# Error when trying to access S3 using jets3t

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3

I know this question has been asked before, but either there was no response or there was no indication from the person originally asking that it was resolved. I am trying to access S3n storage by modifying the S3n interface of Hadoop. I am setting up a file-system called Tachyon on top of S3n. For this, I have to format the file-system. I was getting this error when trying to do so:

```
Connection to tachyon-master... Formatting Tachyon Worker @ tachyon-master
Removing local data under folder: /mnt/ramdisk/tachyonworker/
Connection to tachyon-master closed.
Formatting Tachyon Master @ tachyon-master
Formatting JOURNAL_FOLDER: /home/ubuntu/tachyon-0.5.0/libexec/../journal/
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jets3t/service/S3ServiceException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.createDefaultStore(NativeS3FileSystem.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.initialize(NativeS3FileSystem.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:287)
    at tachyon.UnderFileSystemHdfs.<init>(UnderFileSystemHdfs.java:89)
    at tachyon.UnderFileSystemHdfs.getClient(UnderFileSystemHdfs.java:56)
    at tachyon.UnderFileSystem.get(UnderFileSystem.java:69)
    at tachyon.UnderFileSystem.get(UnderFileSystem.java:54)
    at tachyon.Format.formatFolder(Format.java:32)
    at tachyon.Format.main(Format.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 14 more
```

I set my Hadoop classpath, as suggested by some in this forum, as given below:

```
/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.2.jar
```

I downloaded the latest zip file jets3t-0.9.2.zip. I added the jars in the "jars" folder to this classpath, one if which is shown above. Still, I am getting this error. I would be glad for any help!

Comment: did you make any progress on this?

Comment: ever got a fix for this?